# Regular Expression for specific pattern string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove particular string using regex from below:

Input string:

`{"t":1,"i":"a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1","p":"At DB Server Time: Wed Sep 27 2017 05:27:18 GMT+0000 (UTC), you sent this message: {'t':1,'i':'a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1','p':{'u':'/test/delayed','v':'GET','h':{'X-BH-AgentID':'testagent','X-BH-TempToken':'testagenttemptoken'},'p':'','t':{'t':1000}}}"}`

Remove below string using regular expression:

`At DB Server Time: Wed Sep 27 2017 05:27:18 GMT+0000 (UTC), you sent this message:`

I want below output:

`{"t":1,"i":"a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1","p":" {'t':1,'i':'a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1','p':{'u':'/test/delayed','v':'GET','h':{'X-BH-AgentID':'testagent','X-BH-TempToken':'testagenttemptoken'},'p':'','t':{'t':1000}}}"}`

Comment: I don't understand your example. The "i" property has to change as well ?

Comment: If you want to do something, why not do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a code like this:

```
var input = @"{""t"":1,""i"":""a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1"",""p"":""At DB Server Time: Wed Sep 27 2017 05:27:18 GMT+0000 (UTC), you sent this message: {'t':1,'i':'a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1','p':{'u':'/test/delayed','v':'GET','h':{'X-BH-AgentID':'testagent','X-BH-TempToken':'testagenttemptoken'},'p':'','t':{'t':1000}}}""}";
var pattern = @"At\s+DB\s+Server\s+Time:\s+\w{3}\s+\w{3}\s+\d+\s+\d{4}\s+[0-9:]{8}\s+GMT\+\d+\s+\(UTC\)\s*,\s+you\s+sent\s+this\s+message:";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty);
```

**[C# Demo](http://rextester.com/LXHIIE15497)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```cs
var input = @"{""t"":1,""i"":""a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1"",""p"":""At DB Server Time: Wed Sep 27 2017 05:27:18 GMT+0000 (UTC), you sent this message: {\""t\"":1,\""i\"":\""a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1\"",\""p\"":{\""u\"":\""/test/delayed\"",\""v\"":\""GET\"",\""h\"":{\""X-BH-AgentID\"":\""testagent\"",\""X-BH-TempToken\"":\""testagenttemptoken\""},\""p\"":\""\"",\""t\"":{\""t\"":1000}}}""}";

var pattern = @"""At.*message:";
var replacement = string.Empty;

var rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

You can find a doc there: [link to learn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx).
Basically, you replace the string that you want to delete with nothing.

but remember: at least try do do something instead of asking for other people to code for you next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best method using first p in double quotes

```
            string input = "{\"t\":1,\"i\":\"a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1\",\"p\":\"At DB Server Time: Wed Sep 27 2017 05:27:18 GMT+0000 (UTC), you sent this message: {'t':1,'i':'a32dffdd-c99d-4df5-9296-9ae5fb024dc1','p':{'u':'/test/delayed','v':'GET','h':{'X-BH-AgentID':'testagent','X-BH-TempToken':'testagenttemptoken'},'p':'','t':{'t':1000}}}\"}";
            string pattern = "\"p\":[^\\{]+";
            string mat = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value;
            input = Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"\"p\": ");
```